# Asus PCE-AC51 wifi connection problems on windows 10

Tags: wireless-networking

Been Apple user for a long time but recently decided to have a Windows desktop as well. Did not want to have any cables laying around so I bought Asus PCE-AC51 wireless PCI card for the computer.

Installed the card and driver, I can see all the available networks and connect to my wifi. Sometimes it says unable to connect to network but most of the times it connects and connects to internet, but for a minute or so, after that it either disconnects from wifi network or stays connected to wifi but says there is no internet connection. LAN cable connected to same router connects successfully to internet every time.

Card is 802.11ac, router does not have this option. I switched it from bgn mixed to bg mixed on router. Tried to use only one channel, DHCP on or off, no difference.
On Windows 10 I tried reinstalling the driver, changing the power management settings, manually setting IP and DNS addresses, turning off firewalls and virus protection. Changing public/private network. Nothing has helped, stuck with the cable.

What else can I try? Or is the wifi card just not suitable for my router?

Edit (due to totally useless comment):
Same router and MacBook: no issues
Same router and iPhone: no issues
Same router and PS4: no issues
Same router, same wifi card, same computer, but running Kali Linux: no issues.

Comment: No, the router is very old and probably not suited for the traffic. And everything you said you did just made it worse.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia Thank you for trying to help but this comment is totally useless. Please explain how did reinstalling the drivers made the situation worse.

Comment: I meant the router settings. What you changed can only make it worse.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia Then please be specific. Also using only channel 1 or 6 makes it worse? You yourself recommended this in another topic, although the problem was a bit different but I think trying it was worth the shot. Let's assume the router is rubbish (funnily only when using Windows). Which router would you recommend to buy?

Comment: He's saying that switching the router from bgn to bg was not a smart move. Put it back. You might consider resetting the router to factory reset now considering all the changes you made to it. On the PC bring up Device Manager and verify the wireless is installed and working. Reset the networking (Select the Start button, then select Settings > Network & Internet > Status > Network reset.) then try again.

Comment: @Larryc Set the router back the way it was. Device Manager: the device is working properly. Reset the networking, restarted the computer. Twice was not able to connect to the wifi, third time was able to connect but the fun lasted only for 3 mintues, after that again no internet.

Comment: This card is incompatible with your router. The card is pure 802.11AC, while the router does not support this new protocol. Return this card and buy a more suitable one that supports 802.11 bgn.